# Create mex for Matlab on Linux with different compilers

Tags: linux, matlab, gcc, mex, icc

I know Linux Matlab only has official support for gcc 4.9 for mex.

Does anyone know how to get either the Linux Intel compilers (icc) working with mex on Linux or more recent versions of the gcc?

This is for recent versions of Matlab (2015-2017).

Comment: "this software only support A, how can I make B?" Let me try to answer even if its obvious: You cant, it only supports A

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but have you tried to compile a **dll** file outside Matlab environment with Matlab's C++ API, such like using CMake, or under an IDE like QT and succeed? If you have been successful with your compiler, than there is a good chance to do for **Mex**. FYI, mex is a dll with special entry function mexFunction. You would have to use calllib to load a generic dlls if without that gateway function. I remember I've seen somewhere regarding how to compile mex with cmake.

Comment: OK found it. Hope this help.  [Compile MEX File](https://github.com/zchen24/matlab_example/wiki/Compile-MEX-File)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk about C++ projects. Yes, its possible with newer versions of gcc.

- Check [supported compilers](https://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html) to find out which Matlab uses which gcc version.
- Tell your newer version of gcc to use the ABI version of the gcc version that your Matlab was made in for the compilation of your project and all dependencies.
- Tell Matlab to use the standard c++ library in /usr/lib and not the one it contains itself. It is backwards compatible.

Example with gcc > 4.9.x for Matlab 2017b:

- Matlab 2017b was built with gcc 4.9.x
- gcc 4.9.x is compatible with [CXX ABI version 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)
- use your gcc with compile flag `-fabi-version=8` for your mex file and all dependencies
- in a shell `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` before a call to `matlab`